# Output python logging in realtime to front end

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, python-logging, event-stream

In python Flask app, I can declare a custom stream:

```
from Flask import Response
import logging
from datetime import datetime
from time import sleep

logger = logging.getLogger('my_log_stream')
handler = logging.StreamHandler()
handler.setFormatter = logging.Formatter('[%(asctime)s] %(levelname)s in %(module)s: %(message)s')
logger.addHandler(handler)
```

I can create some fake logging data:

```
def fake_logger_data():
    for i in range(100):
        current_time = datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S') + "\n"
        yield current_time.encode()
        sleep(1)
```

And I can expose the log_stream to the front end:

```
@app.route("/log_stream", methods=["GET"])
def app_log_stream():
    return Response(fake_logger_data(), mimetype="text/event-stream")
```

Which is then displayed simply:

```
<pre id="log_output"></pre>
<script>
    var source = new EventSource("{{ url_for('app_log_stream') }}");
    source.onmessage = function (event) {
        document.getElementById('log_output').textContent += event.data + '\n'
    };
</script>
```

But I can't see how I can connect the logging to the event-stream. I have seen some similar questions that are regularly reading a log file but is there a way to "stream" the logs to an event generator of sorts?

Looking through the Python docs, I was expecting to be able to set the stream location as a function in place of the `fake_logger_data()` above - https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html - but nothing obvious popped up.